# Can I cast spells that require concentration through "Invoke Duplicity"

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, spellcasting, cleric, concentration

Can I use the clone from "Invoke Duplicity" to cast a concentration spell, since the clone requires concentration itself?

For example, could I use the clone to cast invisibility on one of my allies who is too far away from me to cast it normally?

I know that I would lose concentration on the clone when I cast a concentration spell, but would the clone exist long enough to still cast the spell on my ally?

Comment: While there is some difference between a Concentration Spell and the Channel Divinity Concentration mechanic, functionally they are the same and therefore the duplicate question is exactly the answer to this problem.

Comment: I read this as being a different question. The proposed dupe is about casting concentration spell B for an instant effect without breaking concentration on a previously-cast spell A. This question is about switching concentration to spell B, where spell B is cast *through* a clone created by concentrating on spell A.